# How to clean boileplate code in a pandas dataframe by writing a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to write a function to fix some boilerplate code in Jupyter notebooks. An example I'm looking at is:

```
# boilerplate
df_cases.drop( columns=df_cases.columns[8:], inplace=True )
df_cases.columns = [ 'State', 'Country', 'Latitude', 'Longitude',
                     'January', 'February', 'March', 'April' ]
df_deaths.drop( columns=df_deaths.columns[8:], inplace=True )
df_deaths.columns = [ 'State', 'Country', 'Latitude', 'Longitude',
                      'January', 'February', 'March', 'April' ]
df_recoveries.drop( columns=df_recoveries.columns[8:], inplace=True )
df_recoveries.columns = [ 'State', 'Country', 'Latitude', 'Longitude',
                          'January', 'February', 'March', 'April' ]

# fixed
def drop_unneeded_columns ( df ):
    df.drop( columns=df.columns[8:], inplace=True )
    df.columns = [ 'State', 'Country', 'Latitude', 'Longitude',
                   'January', 'February', 'March', 'April' ]
```

But I'm having an issue trying to fix this code:

```
#boilerplate    
df['Age'] = df['Age'].replace( '-', np.nan )
df['Age'] = df['Age'].astype( float )
df['BA'] = df['BA'].replace( '-', np.nan )
df['BA'] = df['BA'].astype( float )
df['OBP'] = df['OBP'].replace( '-', np.nan )
df['OBP'] = df['OBP'].astype( float )
df['SLG'] = df['SLG'].replace( '-', np.nan )
df['SLG'] = df['SLG'].astype( float )
df['OPS'] = df['OPS'].replace( '-', np.nan )
df['OPS'] = df['OPS'].astype( float )
df['OPS+'] = df['OPS+'].replace( '-', np.nan )
df['OPS+'] = df['OPS+'].astype( float )
```

However, all we have is the following code: which is not really working well because we aren't sure on how to reference the columns:

```
# fixed? not working
def replace_hyphens( df ):
    df.replace( '-', np.nan )
    df.astype( float )
    df.columns = [ 'Age', 'BA', 'OBP', 'SLG',
                   'OPS', 'OPS+']
```

Does someone know how we can fix this function?

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to assign the DataFrame's return values to anything. Without specifying `inplace=True`, the result of e.g. `df.replace('-', np.nan)` is computed, but not assigned.

You could try something like this:

```py
def replace_hyphens(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return df.replace('-', np.nan).astype(float)
```

Regarding the columns, you could for instance apply `str.replace` to a subset of them. First you specify the relevant columns with the `DataFrame.loc` method,  then apply a different function (e.g. a lambda expression) and call `DataFrame.apply`. Note that there is probably a more efficient way, and you might get in trouble trying to cast to float for columns which do not contain '-' strings, so you will likely have to build in a check before you call `astype(float)`.

```py
def replace_hyphens(df: pd.DataFrame, cols: list[str]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].apply(
                          lambda s: s.replace('-', np.nan)                         
                      ).astype(float)
    return df

df = replace_hyphens(df,
                     cols=['Age', 'BA', 'OBP', 'SLG',
                           'OPS', 'OPS+']
)
```

With crude check:

```py
def replace_hyphens(df: pd.DataFrame, cols: list[str]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].apply(
                          lambda s: s.replace('-', np.nan)
    for col in cols:
        try:
            df[:, col] = df[:, col].astype(float)
        except TypeError as err:
            print(f"Couldn't cast column to float: {err!r}")
            # Error handling
    return df
```

But I can hardly imagine there is not a better way to do this available if you take the time to look through some of Panda's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only the `-` in the specified columns and use the 'dict-like to_replace' in [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), here's an example.
First the set-up:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 6, "-", 8, 9],
                   'B': [5, 6, "-", 8, 9],
                   'C': [5, 6, "-", 8, 9]})
df #show initial dataframe
```

Gives

```
    A   B   C
0   5   5   5
1   6   6   6
2   -   -   -
3   8   8   8
4   9   9   9
```

Then to alter:

```py
def replace_hyphens( df, col_list):
    df = df.replace({k: '-' for k in col_list}, np.nan)
    df[col_list] = df[col_list].astype(float)
    return df

df = replace_hyphens(df,['A','C'])
df #show result
```

Column B will remain untouched:

```
    A   B   C
0   5.0 5   5.0
1   6.0 6   6.0
2   NaN -   NaN
3   8.0 8   8.0
4   9.0 9   9.0
```

---

Alternatively, you could iterate on the columns replacing the `-` only in each column one at time, like so:

```py
def replace_hyphens( df, col_list):
    for c in col_list:
        df[c] = df[c].replace('-', np.nan)
        df[c] = df[c].astype(float)
    return df

df = replace_hyphens(df,['A','C'])
```